# Jenkins environment variables plugin

Tags: jenkins

I'm looking for a way to create a properties file that will include all environment variables of my application. The idea is to create a file when deploying with jenkins and then use a script to populate the env vars in the AWS instance that the deployment takes place via a codedeploy hook.

What I want to simulate is the heroku experience, where there is a screen with all the env vars as key-value pairs. Is there such a plugin? Right now I'm using a shell script to create the file by echoing the key-value pairs, which works just fine, but I'd prefer something more user friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [ENVINJECT](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) plugin this might suit your requirement